# mysql combine multiple select statement results

Tags: mysql

I have 2 select statements pulling data from 2 tables for the same people.  I know they can be combined via a join, but I can't get the syntax to work for me.

Query 1:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(username,'@',1) AS username, 
COUNT(username) as count,
ROUND(
SUM(
CONVERT(SUBSTRING(contribution_score, -2), UNSIGNED INTEGER)  +
CONVERT(SUBSTRING(focused_score, -2), UNSIGNED INTEGER)  +
CONVERT(SUBSTRING(prepared_score, -2), UNSIGNED INTEGER) + 
CONVERT(SUBSTRING(work_score, -2), UNSIGNED INTEGER)  
)/COUNT(username)/76*100)
as average

FROM project_rubrics
GROUP BY username
LIMIT 0, 90
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT username,COUNT(username) as days FROM logon GROUP BY username
```

The common link is the username field.
I'd like one result set that gives the username, days, and average for each student, but I can't get joins or combined selects to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the UNION keyword is what your looking for see http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx

Comment: Union won't work unless he changes the column name of the second second query and in this case would create two rows per username.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a subquery.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(username,'@',1) AS username, 
COUNT(username) as count,
ROUND(
SUM(
CONVERT(SUBSTRING(contribution_score, -2), UNSIGNED INTEGER)  +
CONVERT(SUBSTRING(focused_score, -2), UNSIGNED INTEGER)  +
CONVERT(SUBSTRING(prepared_score, -2), UNSIGNED INTEGER) + 
CONVERT(SUBSTRING(work_score, -2), UNSIGNED INTEGER)  
)/COUNT(username)/76*100)
as average,

(SELECT COUNT(username) as days FROM logon WHERE logon.username=project_rubrics.username GROUP BY username) as username_count

FROM project_rubrics
GROUP BY username
LIMIT 0, 90
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work.  It returned an error that more than 1 row as returned by the subquery.

Comment: This works for me (different database, but same general idea). Maybe your group by statement in the subquery should specify the table:  SELECT COUNT(username) as days FROM logon WHERE logon.username=project_rubrics.username GROUP BY logon.username.